# Biased random in SQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, random, statistics

I have some entries in my database, in my case Videos with a rating and popularity and other factors. Of all these factors I calculate a likelihood factor or more to say a boost factor.

So I essentially have the fields ID and BOOST.The boost is calculated in a way that it turns out as an integer that represents the percentage of how often this entry should be hit in in comparison.

```
ID  Boost
1   1
2   2
3   7
```

So if I run my random function indefinitely I should end up with X hits on ID 1, twice as much on ID 2 and 7 times as much on ID 3.

So every hit should be random but with a probability of `(boost / sum of boosts)`. So the probability for ID 3 in this example should be 0.7 (because the sum is 10. I choose those values for simplicity).

I thought about something like the following query:

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE CEIL(RAND() * MAX(boost)) >= boost ORDER BY rand();
```

Unfortunately that doesn't work, after considering the following entries in the table:

```
ID  Boost
1   1
2   2
```

It will, with a 50/50 chance, have only the 2nd or both elements to choose from randomly.

So 0.5 hit goes to the second element
And 0.5 hit goes to the (second and first) element which is chosen from randomly so so 0.25 each.
So we end up with a 0.25/0.75 ratio, but it should be 0.33/0.66

I need some modification or new a method to do this with good performance.

I also thought about storing the boost field cumulatively so I just do a range query from (`0-sum()`), but then I would have to re-index everything coming after one item if I change it or develop some swapping algorithm or something... but that's really not elegant and stuff.

Both inserting/updating and selecting should be fast!

Do you have any solutions to this problem?

The best use case to think of is probably advertisement delivery. "Please choose a random ad with given probability"... however i need it for another purpose but just to give you a last picture what it should do.

edit:

Thanks to kens answer i thought about the following approach:

1. calculate a random value from 0-sum(distinct boost)

   SET @randval = (select ceil(rand() * sum(DISTINCT boost)) from test);
2. select the boost factor from all distinct boost factors which added up surpasses the random value

then we have in our 1st example 1 with a 0.1, 2 with a 0.2 and 7 with a 0.7 probability.

1. now select one random entry from all entries having this boost factor

**PROBLEM:** because the count of entries having one boost is always different. For example if there is only 1-boosted entry i get it in 1 of 10 calls, but if there are 1 million with 7, each of them is hardly ever returned...
so this doesnt work out :( trying to refine it.

I have to somehow include the count of entries with this boost factor ... but i am somehow stuck on that...

Comment: okay i am stuck please help me :D i also thought about selecting a subset where i divide the probability by a rand value but that didnt turn out good either ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to generate a random number per row and weight it.

In this case, `RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))` gets around the "per query" evaluation of `RAND`. Then simply multiply it by boost and ORDER BY the result DESC. The `SUM..OVER` gives you the total boost

```
DECLARE @sample TABLE (id int, boost int)

INSERT @sample VALUES (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 7)

SELECT
    RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * boost  AS weighted,
    SUM(boost) OVER () AS boostcount,
    id
FROM
    @sample
GROUP BY
    id, boost
ORDER BY
    weighted DESC
```

If you have wildly different boost values (which I think you mentioned), I'd also consider using LOG (which is base e) to smooth the distribution.

Finally, ORDER BY NEWID() is a randomness that would take no account of boost. It's useful to seed RAND but not by itself.

This sample was put together on SQL Server 2008, BTW

Comment: +1 looks promising, gotta port it to mysql and think it through once more b4 accepting :)

Comment: @Joe Hopfgartner: quite close to standard SQL so hopefully straightforward

Answer (score 2):

I dare to suggest straightforward solution with two queries, using cumulative boost calculation.

First, select sum of boosts, and generate some number between 0 and boost sum:

```
select ceil(rand() * sum(boost)) from table;
```

This value should be stored as a variable, let's call it {random_number}

Then, select table rows, calculating cumulative sum of boosts, and find the first row, which has cumulative boost greater than {random number}:

```
SET @cumulative_boost=0;
SELECT
  id,
  @cumulative_boost:=(@cumulative_boost + boost) AS cumulative_boost,
FROM
  table
WHERE
  cumulative_boost >= {random_number}
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: i like the approach but this whole adding up is exactly the thing i wanted to avoid. but +1 because you may have pointed me into the right direction. i am just working on a slution where i just add up the boosts commulative and then know exactly what boost value to choose randomly from. havent thought it through completely yet but i think it will do.

Comment: It would be good if you publish your solution here when you work it out, since this problem looks rather interesting.

Comment: didnt work out unfortunately but i am trying to refine it. there must be a way this is such a common problem!

Answer (score 0):

My problem was similar: Every person had a calculated number of tickets in the final draw. If you had more tickets then you would have an higher chance to win "the lottery".

Since I didn't trust any of the found results `rand() * multiplier` or the one with `-log(rand())` on the web I wanted to implement my own straightforward solution.

What I did and in your case would look a little bit like this:

```
(SELECT id, boost FROM foo) AS values
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id % 100 + 1 AS counter 
    FROM user 
    GROUP BY counter) AS numbers ON numbers.counter <= values.boost
ORDER BY RAND()
```

Since I don't have to run it often I don't really care about future performance and at the moment it was fast for me.

Before I used this query I checked two things:

1. The maximum number of `boost` is less than the maximum returned in the number query
2. That the inner query returns ALL numbers between 1..100. It might not depending on your table!

Since I have all distinct numbers between 1..100 then joining on `numbers.counter <= values.boost` would mean that if a row has a boost of 2 it would end up duplicated in the final result. If a row has a boost of 100 it would end up in the final set 100 times. Or in another words. If sum of boosts is 4212 which it was in my case you would have 4212 rows in the final set.

Finally I let MySql sort it randomly.

**Edit:** For the inner query to work properly make sure to use a large table, or make sure that the id's don't skip any numbers. Better yet and probably a bit faster you might even create a temporary table which would simply have all numbers between 1..n. Then you could simply use `INNER JOIN numbers ON numbers.id <= values.boost`