# php - how do I display 5 results from possible 50 randomly but ensure all results are displayed equal amount

Tags: php

In php - how do I display 5 results from possible 50 randomly but ensure all results are displayed equal amount.

For example table has 50 entries.
I wish to show 5 of these randomly with every page load but also need to ensure all results are displayed rotationally an equal number of times. 
I've spent hours googling for this but can't work it out - would very much like your help please.

Comment: it will be equal by definition, lol. no need to worry

Comment: lol just as comforting as the fact that the state of germany cant go bankrupt by constitution ;D

Comment: And of course everyone tend to answer with mathematical precision while for the web page it's way overkill

Answer (score 2):

please scroll down for "biased randomness" if you dont want to read.

In mysql you can just use `SeleCT * From table order by rand() limit 5`.

What you want just does not work. Its logically contradicting.

You have to understand that complete randomness by definition means equal distribution after an infinite period of time.

The longer the interval of selection the more evenly the distribution.

If you MUST have even distribution of selection for example every 24h interval, you cannot use a random algorithm. It is by definition contradicting.

It really depends no what your goal is.

You could for example take some element by random and then lower the possibity for the same element to be re-chosen at the next run. This way you can do a heuristic that gives you a more evenly distribution after a shorter amount of time. But its not random. Well certain parts are.

You could also randomly select from your database, mark the elements as selected, and now select only from those not yet selected. When no element is left, reset all.

Very trivial but might do your job.

You can also do something like that with timestamps to make the distribution a bit more elegant.

This could probably look like ORDER BY `RAND()*((timestamps-min(timestamps))/(max(timetamps)-min(timestamps))) DESC` or something like that. Basically you could normalize the timestamp of selection of an entry using the time interval window so it gets something between 0 and 1 and then multiply it by rand.. then you have 50% fresh stuff less likely selected and 50% randomness... i am not sure about the formular above, just typed it down. probably wrong but the principle works.

I think what you want is generally referred to as "biased randomness". there are a lot of papers on that and some articles on SO. for example here:

[Biased random in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4063742/biased-random-in-sql)

Answer (score 1):

Copy the 50 results to some temporary place (file, database, whatever you use). Then everytime you need random values, select 5 random values from the 50 and delete them from your temporary data set.

Once your temporary data set is empty, create a new one copying the original again.

Comment: Thanks yankee - that sounds like a simple and easy way to do it.  Cheers!