# Modyfing MySQL query to work with PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I get MySQL query from: [Biased random in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4063742/biased-random-in-sql) but it unfortunately doesn't work with PostgreSQL:

```
DECLARE @sample TABLE (id int, boost int)

INSERT @sample VALUES (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 7)

SELECT
    RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * boost  AS weighted,
    SUM(boost) OVER () AS boostcount,
    id
FROM
    @sample
GROUP BY
    id, boost
ORDER BY
    weighted DESC
```

It says that NEWID() function doesn't exists. Anyone could help me with modyfing this query?

Big thanks!

Comment: newid() is not a MySQL function either.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear if you refer to MySQL (which does not have a `newid()` function) or to SQL Server (which does have a `newid()` function and is also targeted in the answer you have linked to).

The standard way to generate UUIDs in Postgres is to install the UUID contrib module and then use one of the supplied functions to generate a UUID:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/uuid-ossp.html

The module is installed by running `create extension "uuid-ossp"` while being connected as the superuser (usually postgres).

If you are on an older version of PostgreSQL you will need to run the the script `uuid-ossp.sql` from the contrib folder (which is part of your PostgreSQL installation)

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL doesn't support an equivalent to the Microsoft SQL Server function `newid()`

You have to implement if you want.

A good implementation can be found [HERE](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/56562/Creating-newid-for-PostgreSQL)

You can also use the  [uuid-ossp Module](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/uuid-ossp.html), but i never tried.